# Method not defined as a function (while defined as one)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, discord, discord.js

I am experimenting a strange issue: at the beginning of my code, I defined a function like so:

```
function rootEmbed()
{
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(config.embedColor);
    return embed;
    //returns an object
}
```

Later in the same file, I define another function which calls the one above, like so:

```
function commandList()
{
    var embed = rootEmbed();
    //....
}
```

Calling that function causes no problem, however calling the following function returns an error that says

```
(node:4988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: rootEmbed is not a function
```

Here is the told function:

```
function voidTrader(trader)
{
    var rootEmbed = rootEmbed();
    //...
}
```

I can't figure out why does the `voidTrader()` method causes an error while `commandList()` turns out perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

If you want the full code, you can find it [here](https://hastebin.com/isegufogow.js).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Wilfred has explained it well. You will not face it when you move the below code out of function.                     var rootEmbed = rootEmbed();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a combination of variable hoisting and variable shadowing. When you initialize a variable `var x = 5`, what happens is that `var x` is hoisted to the top of the code file. However, function **declarations** are hoisted even higher. Meaning that when your file is run, this is what is happening:

```
function rootEmbed (){//...code here}
var rootEmbed = undefined;
```

To fix this problem, change this:

```
function voidTrader(trader)
{
    var rootEmbed = rootEmbed();
    //...
}
```

To something like this:

```
function voidTrader(trader)
{
    var rootEmbedResult = rootEmbed();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel stupid right now... It was a matter of variable name all along ! ('^_^)

Comment: Happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem at lines 25-26:

```
var year = "" + stamp.getYear();
var year = twoDigits("20" + year.substr(-2));
```

`year` is declared with `var` twice.